# PDO mixing unnamed and named parameters

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to use this for a basic search with pagination:

```
$construct = '? AND ? AND..';

$query = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM something WHERE something LIKE ' . $construct . ' LIMIT :offset, :results');
```

The only reason I'm mixing them is because unnamed parameters can't have int values because of a PHP bug apparently: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639

However if I don't mix them, how can I search for a variable amount of terms using bindings?

**Update**

After messing around with it I solved it more or less using named parameters and some loops:

```
    // build prepared statement
    $construct = '';
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $searchArrayCount; $x++) {
        $construct .= ($x < $searchArrayCount)
                    ? ":var$x OR name LIKE "
                    : ":var$x LIMIT :start, :perPage";
    }

    $query = $database->prepare('SELECT something FROM something WHERE name LIKE ' . $construct);

    // bind parameters
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $searchArrayCount; $x++) {
        $searchArray[$x] = "%$searchArray[$x]%";
        $query->bindParam(":var$x", $searchArray[$x]);
    }

    $query->bindParam(':start', $searchArrayCount, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':perPage', $perPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

If there's a more optimal way of going about this I'd love to be informed.

Answer (score 1):

Unnamed parameters can have int values. Just define explicit type in bind function.

There can be problem with variables data type. It is good to use `intval()`function before.

Your solution in unnamed data type can look like this:

```
$counter = 0;

//build prepared statement

$query = $database->prepare('SELECT something FROM something WHERE 0 OR '.
implode(' OR ', array_fill(0 , $searchArrayCount, 'name LIKE ?')).
        ' LIMIT ?, ?');

// bind parameters
foreach($searchArray as $value)
{
    $counter++;
    $query->bindValue($counter, ('%'.$value.'%'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
}

$query->bindValue(($counter+1), ($page*$perPage), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(($counter+2), $perPage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Note I used rather `bindValue()` before `bindParam()`.
And beware from the first parameter of `LIMIT`. If the count will be here then the selection will be start on the end of the data and no rows will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Faced to a similar problem, in the end I just skipped bind parameters in the LIMIT clause:

```
sprintf('LIMIT %d, %d', $offset, $size);
```

Another workaround (if your system supports it) is to switch to native parameter binding. Apparently, it's the emulation layer the one that exhibits this behaviour:

```
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
```